# MySQl storage procedures

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, storage

I have a little problem. Looks like the procedure does not exist. Somehow it's dropped after the creation. I get different error each time i change something. I'm not really sure what's causing the error, maybe I'm not allowed to drop procedures and creating them in the same query.

I hope you guys can help me out.

```
drop procedure if exists refIntChk;

DELIMITER //  

    CREATE PROCEDURE refIntChk(IN district INT(11), OUT b INT(1)) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE b INT(1);
        IF district IN (select dist FROM t13)
        THEN
            SET b = 1;
            ELSE 
            SET b = 0;
        END IF;
    END; //

DELIMITER ;

drop procedure gen if exists ;

DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE gen() 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rows INT(11) DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(dist) FROM t13);
        DECLARE district INT(11);
        DECLARE custname VARCHAR(16);
        DECLARE revenue FLOAT;
        DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 10000;
        DECLARE outvar INT(11);

        WHILE x > 0 
        DO
            SET district = FLOOR(RAND()*rows)+1;
            CALL refIntChk(district, outvar);
            IF outvar = 1 
            THEN        
                SET custname = substring(MD5(RAND()), -16);
                SET revenue = (RAND() * 10);
                INSERT INTO t14 VALUES(NULL, custname, district, revenue);
                SET x = x - 1;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;
    END;//

DELIMITER ;

CALL gen();
```

Comment: What kinds of errors are you getting?

Comment: You probably mean stored procedures, not storage :))

Answer (score 1):

When you get errors, it's usually good to run each statement, one by one, and see which one is producing the error.

The second `DROP` procedure statement should be:

```
drop procedure if exists  gen;
```